# awk system call

Tags: bash, awk

I want to use awk and the `system()` function to move a couple of directories around.

I have a file that I want to process with `awk` names `file.cfg` which is organized in the following way:

```
/path1 /path2 
/some_path /some_other_path 
and so on..
```

each first path is separated from the second path by a whitespace
So here's how I did it:

```
awk '{system(mv -R $1" "$2)}' file.cfg
```

but it doesn't work and I get

```
sh: 0/home/my_user/path1: No such file or directory
```

But `file.cfg` looks like this:

```
/home/my_user/path1 /home/my_user/path2
```

and there is no 0 before `/home`. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to quote the command you give to `system`:

```
awk '{system("mv -R " $1 " " $2)}' file.cfg
```

Currently `mv -R` is interpreted as the value of variable mv minus the value of R, which is `0` since neither is defined.

Comment: Seems like "Error: variables `mv`, `R` not defined" would make more sense in this case.  I wonder if `awk` accepts pull requests...

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use xargs?

```
cat file.cfg | xargs -n 2 mv
```

This will pass tokens (separated by whitespace) from your file into mv in groups of two.

Comment: @EdMorton is there a particular reason that xargs is better in this case? Without looking into it too much, I suspect that the xargs method invokes one more process than just using awk. Still O(n), but is awk not at least pedantically better?

Comment: @bschlueter I haven't thought at all about the prose/cons of using xargs for this, I just said it'd be wrong to use awk for it since for every `mv` call you'd be using shell to call awk to call system to call shell to call mv instead of simply having shell call mv. awk is just for manipulating text, the shell is for manipulating files and processes.

Comment: @EdMorton That's not accurate, [g]awk would read the file once–just as cat does–and for each line in the file, execute its system command, which in linux uses the C system library function which uses fork to execute the provided command (see https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/builtin.c?h=gawk-4.2-stable#n2167). I may just look into precisely how barely more efficient this must be.

Comment: My [test](https://gist.github.com/schlueter/ae4c9f5510110c5358db074779df3b3c) actually showed that the xargs approach is faster: repeating each of `cat paired-words | xargs -n2 mv`, `awk '{system("mv " $1 " " $2)}' paired-words`, and an additional `cat paired-words | xargs -n2 -P8 mv` 100x resulted in the first taking loosely half as long as the second and twice as long as the second. I suspect this is due superior buffering and parallelism on xargs part.

Comment: @bschlueter what I said is 100% accurate but I wasn't primarily talking about efficiency, I was mainly talking about conceptually. You need shell to call mv, right? So you NEED `shell { mv }` but when you introduce awk you're turning that into `shell { awk { system { shell { mv } } } }` - completely ludicrous and unnecessary with absolutely zero benefits. If you are going to use xargs you don't need cat and a pipe, btw, input redirection works just fine, e.g. `< file xargs ...`. Again though I'm not making any claims about how to do the job in shell, just that you should NOT introduce awk.

Comment: @EdMorton you had said "for every mv call you'd be using shell to call awk" which is the only inaccuracy I was calling out. Based on my updated [test gist](https://gist.github.com/schlueter/ae4c9f5510110c5358db074779df3b3c), `< directory-names.txt xargs -n2 mv` is the fastest version.

Comment: @EdMorton whenever you feel the need to post something as condescending and "absolute" again, just take a step back and don't.

Comment: @FlorianHeigl what are you talking about?

Comment: whew and i thought i was the only one