# Calling Imagemagick from awk?

Tags: csv, awk, imagemagick

I have a CSV of image details I want to loop over in a bash script. `awk` seems like an obvious choice to loop over the data.

For each row, I want to take the values, and use them to do Imagemagick stuff. The following isn't working (obviously):

```
awk -F, '{ magick "source.png" "$1.jpg" }' images.csv
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823216/awk-system-call, but you are going to overwrite `source.png` again and again if you don't use a variable name

Comment: if this is the *only* thing the `awk` script is going to do then you're likely better off just using a `bash` loop, ie, `awk` doesn't provide any benefit in this case

Comment: You're probably right @markp-fuso. I know next to nothing about bash.  Right now, I'm able to loop over my CSV in one simple line. Is there a tute that could teach me how to use a bash loop over a CSV and access each field as variable in the loop? All my searching led me to awk.

Comment: have you tried a (web) search on `bash loop csv`?

Comment: Forgetting `awk` and **ImageMagick** for a moment, please take a step back, click [edit] and say what you are *actually* trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `AWK` excels at processing structured text data, although it can be used to summon commands using [`system`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) function it is less handy for that than some other language, e.g. `python` has module of standard library called [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) which is more feature-rich.

If you wish to use `awk` for this task anyway, then I suggest preparing output to be feed into `bash` command, say you have `file.txt` with following content

```
file1.jpg,file1.bmp
file2.png,file2.bmp
file3.webp,file3.bmp
```

and you have files listed in 1st column in current working directory and wish to convert them to files shown in 2nd column and access to `convert` command, then you might do

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print "convert \"" $1 "\" \"" $2 "\""}' file.txt | bash
```

which is equvialent to starting `bash` and doing

```
convert "file1.jpg" "file1.bmp"
convert "file2.png" "file2.bmp"
convert "file3.webp" "file3.bmp"
```

Observe that I have used literal `"` to enclose filenames, so it should work with names containing spaces. **Disclaimer**: it might fail if name containing special character, e.g. `"`.